# Angular router-outlet jasmine test

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, jasmine, router-outlet

Im testing web-app navigation via Jasmine spec with `RouterTestingModule` however having trouble with nested `fixture.whenStable().then(() => {})`.

For example: 
I click on a link, then another link and then another link, each time router-outlet changes which component it displays. So far this is the only way I figured to test (without e2e tests) is to follow below pattern:

```
(component setup)
...
it('test name', async(() => {
 fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.link').click();

 fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
   fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.link2').click();

   fixture.whenStable().then(() => { 
     fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.link3').click();

     fixture.whenStable().then(() => { 
        expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.element')).toBeTruthy();
     });
   });
 });
});
```

But this is a bit of an insane way of writing tests. I figure to try `fakeAsync` with `tick()` and `flush()` however it doesn't help, as component don't appear (render) in place of `router-outlet`.

Is there a way to accomplish my test without having a nested promise structure? Can `fakeAsync` help in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
it('test name', async () => { // use actual async function to be able to use await
 fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.link').click();

 await fixture.whenStable();
 fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.link2').click();

 await fixture.whenStable();
 fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.link3').click();

 await fixture.whenStable()
 expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.element')).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on fakeAsync?

Comment: From my knowledge `fakeAsync` allows you to simulate time flow in ngZone with use of `tick` basicaly it observes ongoing async actions and keeps control about their time flow. You can have async function under fakeAsync if you want to use await structure for awaiting resolving some promises but if some async error will be throw in them it will be caught by fakeAsyc scope